# Constraining two ViewController containers together to fill the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistoryboard

I want to have two views within a parent view. One view should be the exact size of its contents, and then the second view fills in whatever space is left.

I have the following setup in an iOS Storyboard:

[image]

My main ViewController has two ViewController containers, one above the other.

The bottom ViewController is intended to have a static height, determined by its content. In this case, it has a button with a top, bottom and trailing constraint. As such, if you knew the height of the button, you should be able to determine the height of the bottom ViewController.

The top ViewController is intended to be variable - it has a button constrained to the middle center of its parent view. No matter the height or width of the parent view, the inner button will always center itself.

Within the main ViewController, the top view controller is constrained to the main view's top and sides, while the bottom view controller is constrained to the main view's bottom and sides. Then, the bottom of the top view, and the top of the bottom view are constrained to each other. This breaks because iOS tries to determine the size of the main view before the bottom view (or something to that effect).

How can I have the bottom view equal the height of its contents, and have the top view fill in any space left over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with **Storyboard only**... you'll need to add a little code.

First, in Storyboard / Interface Builder:

- constrain the Bottom Container to view (safe-area) Leading / Trailing / Bottom
- give it a Height constraint - the value doesn't really matter at this point, just something to allow you to see the approximate layout
- give that Height constraint `Priority: Low (250)`. That will allow it to grow / shrink based on the auto-layout size of its embedded view.
- constrain the Top Container to view (safe-area) Top / Leading / Trailing
- constrain the Bottom of the Top container to the Top of the Bottom container

IB automatically gives you "default" view controllers when you add container views, set to the size of the container. Use the **Attributes** and **Size** Inspector panes to change "Simulated Metrics" and Size to `Freeform`. That allows you to work on the "sub View Controllers" at the sizes you want.

Here's an example of how it could look:

[image]

When embedding a View Controller in a `UIContainerView`, an "embed segue" is automatically created, and you can get a reference to the "sub" view controllers (and their views) in `prepare(for segue: ...)`. Use that to grab references to the views, so you can modify *their* constraints.

So your `viewDidLoad()` func will contain something like this:

```
    // a View Controller's "root" view loads with
    //      .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    // but we want to let auto-layout change it
    topVCView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    botVCView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        // constrain all 4 sides of top view to top container
        //  because the Top container view has a Priority: 1000 height constraint,
        //  this will "fit" the top VC's view into the auto-layout sized top container
        topVCView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainerView.topAnchor),
        topVCView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainerView.bottomAnchor),
        topVCView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainerView.leadingAnchor),
        topVCView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainerView.trailingAnchor),

        // constrain all 4 sides of bottom view to bottom container
        //  because the Bottom container view has a Priority: 250 height constraint,
        //  the auto-layout height of the Bottom VC's view will determine the height of the bottom container
        botVCView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainerView.topAnchor),
        botVCView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainerView.bottomAnchor),
        botVCView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainerView.leadingAnchor),
        botVCView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainerView.trailingAnchor),

    ])
```

and here is an example of how it could look at run-time:

[image]

Had another "auto-sizing container view" example up on GitHub, so I added your layout to a second example. You can get it here, so you can examine the layout, constraints and code (and run it to see the results): https://github.com/DonMag/AutosizeContainer